# Adding a parameter to Jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have this JSON Ajax function

```
$.ajax({
  url: "?page=" + page,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
      $("#feed").append("<li>" + this.message + "</li>");
    });
  }
});
```

However, I would like to be able to pass a variable into it, so this.message could also be this.image, or this.link. I tried doing this.

```
    $.each(data, function() {
      $("#feed").append("<li>" + myVar + "</li>");
    });
```

and setting `myVar = 'this.picture'`, however it treated myVar as a string and it didn't work. How can I pass in a variable so I can achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
... + this[myVar] + ...
```

where `myVar = 'picture'`, or whatever other field it is that you want to display.

This is the standard syntax for accessing a named property of an object when the name is itself a variable rather than a literal token.

Comment: [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation). 60% of the time, it works every time.

Comment: @Matt except when you put it in quotes... ;-)

Comment: I am so not awake yet. ...I am also kind of amazed at the other answers

Answer (score -1):

First of all you must make sure that "picture" or "link" are being passed into your returned Json object.

Then try replacing this with data as in: data.picture or data.link.

Answer (score -1):

You want that the callback to be parameterized use the $.when

Use [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
    var m = $.ajax({
           url: "?page=" + page,   
           dataType: "json"   
        });

     var callback = function(link)
     {   
         return function(data){
                    alert(link); //Can access data and link here
            }
     }

     $.when(m)
      .then(callback(link));
```